# Enable submit button for Cancel even if required fields are empty

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, frontend

I have 2 submit buttons, one for submitting the form and the other for cancelling the submission and redirecting. When clicking the Cancel submit button, it doesn't simply cancel and go back to the processing PHP script. It requires the required fields to be filled for the cancel button to work. I don't understand what is wrong with this. Please check my code below and suggest possible solutions.

```
{include file="header.tpl" page_name='Amazon Order Adjustment' extra_javascript='<script language="JavaScript" src="includes/update_shipping_info.js"></script>'}

{literal}
<style type="text/css">
#loading-icon {
    position: absolute; 
    top: 75px; 
    right: 250px; width: 
    32px; height: 32px;
    display: none; 
    background: url('/images/lightbox/loading.gif');
}
</style>
{/literal}

{if isset($tpl_error_msg) }
    <div id="message">{$tpl_error_msg}</div>
{/if}

{include file='view_order_snippet.tpl'}

<form name="amazon_order_adjustment" id="amazon_order_adjustment" method="post" action="amazon_order_adjustment.php?id={$id}&{$search_params}">
        <div class="row">
            <fieldset>
            <legend>Order Line Items</legend>
                <table id="table2" style="position: relative; float: left;">
                    <tr valign="top">
                        <th width="10%"></th>
                        <th width="10%">SKU</th>
                        <th width="30%">Item</th>
                        <th width="5%">Qty</th>
                        <th width="10%">Status</th>
                        <th width="15%">Ship Mode</th>
                        <th width="20%">Tracking#</th>
                    </tr>
                    {if !($update_shipping_info_flag)}
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="7" align="center">No Items to display</td>
                        </tr>
                    {else}
                        {section name=lineitems loop=$tpl_order_list}
                            <tr id=row1 valign="top">
                                <td><input type="radio" name="check[]" value="{$tpl_order_list[lineitems].id}">
                                <input type="hidden" name="vendor_id_array[]" value="{$tpl_order_list[lineitems].vendor_fk}">
                                </td>
                                <td>{$tpl_order_list[lineitems].sku}
                                <td>{$tpl_order_list[lineitems].item_description}</td>
                                <td>{$tpl_order_list[lineitems].quantity}</td>
                                <td>{$tpl_order_list[lineitems].item_status}</td>
                                <td>{$tpl_order_list[lineitems].shipping_mode}</td>
                                {if $tpl_order_list[lineitems].shipping_tracking_no == ""}
                                <td>N/A</td>
                                {else}
                                <td>{$tpl_order_list[lineitems].shipping_tracking_no}</td>
                                {/if}
                            </tr>
                        {/section}
                    {/if}
                    <tr>
                        <td align="right" colspan="3">Action Type</td>
                        <td align="left" colspan="4">
                            <select id="action_type" name="action_type" required>   
                                <option value="">Select Action</option>
                                {html_options options=$tpl_action_type}
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="right" colspan="3">Enter Refund Amount</td>
                        <td align="left" colspan="4"><input type="number" step="1" min="" id="refund_amount" name="refund_amount" value="" required /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="right" colspan="3">Adjustment Reason</td>
                        <td align="left" colspan="4">
                            <select id="AdjustmentReason" name="AdjustmentReason" required> 
                                <option value="" selected="selected">Select Adjustment Reason</option>
                                {html_options options=$tpl_adjustment_reason}                           
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="right" colspan="3">Adjustment Type</td>
                        <td align="left" colspan="4">
                            <select id="adjustment_type" name="adjustment_type" required>   
                                <option value="" selected="selected">Select Adjustment Type</option>
                                {html_options options=$tpl_adjustment_type}                             
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr id="adjustment_buyer_price">
                        <td align="right" colspan="3">Adjustment Buyer Price Type</td>
                        <td align="left" colspan="4">
                            <select id="AdjustmentBuyerPrice" name="AdjustmentBuyerPrice">  
                                <option value="">Select Adjustment Buyer Price Type</option>
                                {html_options options=$tpl_adjustment_buyer_price}
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <input type="hidden" id="tpl_grand_total_box" name="tpl_grand_total_box" value="{$tpl_grand_total}">
            <input type="hidden" id="tpl_tax_box" name="tpl_tax_box" value="{$tpl_tax}">
            <input type="submit" id="save_button" name="submit_action" value="refund" class="button">
            <input type="button" id="cancel_button" name="submit_action" value="Cancel" class="button">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
{literal}
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#adjustment_buyer_price').hide(); 
    $("#adjustment_type").change(function () {
        var cur_option_val = $(this).val(); 
        if (cur_option_val == "ItemPriceAdjustments") {
            $('#adjustment_buyer_price').show(); 
            $('#AdjustmentBuyerPrice').attr("required", "required") //add required
        } else {
            $('#adjustment_buyer_price').hide();
            $('#AdjustmentBuyerPrice').removeAttr("required") //remove required.
        }
    });
    $(function() {
        $('#cancel_button').click(function() {
            $("#amazon_order_adjustment").submit();
        });
    });     
}); 
</script>
{/literal}
{include file="footer.tpl"}
```

Comment: *I have 2 submit buttons, one for submitting the form and the other for cancelling the submission and redirecting.* <-- Hold on then. You should have one submit button and one regular button then, not two submit buttons.

Comment: The code for the submit and the cancel button is as `<input type="submit" id="save_button" name="submit_action" value="refund" class="button">
   <input type="button" id="cancel_button" name="submit_action" value="Cancel" class="button">` I need both the buttons to to submit the form so that I can validate it in the server side script.

Comment: You are showing the code for your cancel button as `input type="submit" id="cancel_button"`, not `input type="button" id="cancel_button"`. And why would you want a cancel button to submit and validate if your goal is to not submit?

Comment: Change made in VS code now. I want a cancel button to submit the form and redirect the page to something else since the submit value=cancel.

Comment: That's not how you should do it since a submit button will trigger form validation. Just use a regular button and in that button's `click` event handler, do whatever you need to. You can still redirect, but this will allow you to bypass the validation.

Comment: Okay, will do as advised. Thank you

Comment: With the click event handler, I don't get $_POST[] contents in the processing PHP script although form gets submitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your cancel button is clicked you can remove `required` attribute from all inputs and then submit your form in this way `$_POST` datas for input will also get send to server .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(function() {
  $('#cancel_button').click(function() {
    $("input , select ").removeAttr("required") //remove required attr 
    $("#amazon_order_adjustment").append("<input type='hidden' name='submit_action' value='Cancel'>") //add this to know which button click
    $("#amazon_order_adjustment").submit(); //submit
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="amazon_order_adjustment" id="amazon_order_adjustment" method="post" action="amazon_order_adjustment.php?id={$id}&{$search_params}">
  <div class="row">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Order Line Items</legend>
      <table id="table2" style="position: relative; float: left;">
        <tr valign="top">
          <th width="10%"></th>
          <th width="10%">SKU</th>
          <th width="30%">Item</th>
          <th width="5%">Qty</th>
          <th width="10%">Status</th>
          <th width="15%">Ship Mode</th>
          <th width="20%">Tracking#</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="7" align="center">No Items to display</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id=row1 valign="top">
          <td><input type="radio" name="check[]" value="1">
            <input type="hidden" name="vendor_id_array[]" value="2">
          </td>
          <td>A
            <td>B</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>ok</td>
            <td>htm</td>
            <td>N/A</td>


        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td align="right" colspan="3">Action Type</td>
          <td align="left" colspan="4">
            <select id="action_type" name="action_type" required>
              <option value="">Select Action</option>
              <option value="">A</option>
            </select>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="right" colspan="3">Enter Refund Amount</td>
          <td align="left" colspan="4"><input type="number" step="1" min="" id="refund_amount" name="refund_amount" value="" required /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="right" colspan="3">Adjustment Reason</td>
          <td align="left" colspan="4">
            <select id="AdjustmentReason" name="AdjustmentReason" required>
              <option value="" selected="selected">Select Adjustment Reason</option>
              <option value="">A</option>
            </select>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="right" colspan="3">Adjustment Type</td>
          <td align="left" colspan="4">
            <select id="adjustment_type" name="adjustment_type" required>
              <option value="" selected="selected">Select Adjustment Type</option>
              <option value="ItemPriceAdjustments">ItemPriceAdjustments</option>
              <option value="ItemPriceAdjustments1">5</option>

            </select>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="adjustment_buyer_price">
          <td align="right" colspan="3">Adjustment Buyer Price Type</td>
          <td align="left" colspan="4">
            <!--remove required from here-->
            <select id="AdjustmentBuyerPrice" name="AdjustmentBuyerPrice">
              <option value="">Select Adjustment Buyer Price Type</option>
              <option value="">A</option>

            </select>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </fieldset>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <input type="hidden" id="tpl_grand_total_box" name="tpl_grand_total_box" value="{$tpl_grand_total}">
    <input type="hidden" id="tpl_tax_box" name="tpl_tax_box" value="{$tpl_tax}">
    <input type="submit" id="save_button" name="submit_action" value="refund" class="button">
    <input type="button" id="cancel_button" name="submit_action" value="Cancel" class="button">
  </div>

</form>
```

Comment: I need to add a simple "Thank you for the submission" alert using JavaScript in this page https://packedwithpurpose.gifts/client-landing-page-request/ Since this page uses an embedded form, I find it difficult to add it. Can you please have a look and suggest something?

Comment: Hi, something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/fyv5r3sL/) ?

Comment: Exactly. Thanks, but we decided to drop this because using custom JS on the current project is not desirable due to some conflict. Thank you for always being there to help others. Happy weekend Swati.

Comment: hope you are doing great. I remember your help always. I am still a beginner at JavaScript despite being in the IT for 2 years. There is a task involving only JS code, that I'm trying to first complete on the staging server. It is a part of an order management system. I would kindly request you to invest a few minutes of your valuable time in just pointing out the cause of the issue so that I will proceed from there. The issue seems to  be difficult to put in words. If you are comfortable, I share the access credentials so that you can have a look and guide me. Please share your skype.

Answer (score 1):

Use `<input type="button" ...>` instead that `<input type="submit" ...>` for `cancel` button

Comment: This is a question, not an answer and should be a comment, just like what I've already posted as a comment.

Comment: It's better, but because this is such a basic problem, again a comment is really most appropriate. This would fall under the "the problem is a typo" category IMO.

Comment: I saw your comment after that I write this answere

Comment: You can just delete the answer.

Comment: ok, next time I'll comment instead answere.

Comment: You don't have to wait until next time. You can just delete this one.